# best practice for avoid connection timeout when using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

i need to know best practice for avoid connection timeout when using LINQ to SQL in .net applications specially when returning `IQueryable<T>`from data access tiers or layers.

I get "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached." error when testing my asp.net application for webstress tests
?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.geekscrapbook.com/2010/08/13/connection-timeout-using-linq-datacontext/

Link will explain you what will be the reason of Timeouut using LINQ to SQl.You can manually increase the query execution time.By default its 30 sec.
According to  Visual studio 2008 Go to

> Tools->Database Tools->Query & view
>   design

Here you will get the option to increase the execution time.
Hope it helps you.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks Prateek,Actually the issue is if you returning IQueryable<T> from your data access layer(DAL) you cannot use using statement for data context

Answer (score 4):

You need to increase the `CommandTimeout` property value in your `DataContext` object (the default value is 30 seconds), it is measured in seconds, for example:

> var myDataContext = new MyDbDataContext(myConnectionString)
>                                           {
>                                               CommandTimeout = 120
>                                           };
>           var rows = myDataContext.sp_Agent__Select(agentId);

Comment: This would seem to be a better solution as you don't want to necessarily set the time out for every project that is created

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you might wanna check if the server is actually up. I ran into this problem - turns out i forgot to restart the MSSQL service after stopping it for maintenance.

Basic noob mistake, but caused me a weeks headache